# How to show titles gotten from my database for my application blogposts

Tags: php, codeigniter, page-title

I am a newbie in codeigniter, I want to show dynamic titles gotten from my database for my application blogposts. i tried the below code but i kept getting "undefined variable error".

Below is the controller

```
function blogpost(){
$entry_slug = $this->uri->segment(2);

    $config['total_rows'] = $this->Client_model->get_post_count();
    $config['per_page'] = 5;
   
$data['queries'] = $this->Client_model->get_all_post($config['per_page']);

$result = $this->Client_model->get_post($entry_slug,$entry_name); 

$data['title'] = $result['entry_name'];

$data['post']= $this->Client_model->get_post($entry_slug,$entry_name);
$this->load->view('templates/headerss', $data);
$this->load->view('pages/blogpost');
$this->load->view('templates/footerss');
}
```

The model is

```
    function get_post($entry_slug,$entry_name){
$this->db->select();
$this->db->from('entry');
$this->db->where('entry_slug',$entry_slug);
$post = $this->db->get();
return $post->result_array(); }
```

my view is

```
 <title><?php if (!empty($title)) echo $title;?></title>
```

Please help me out, I have been stuck on this for days. I really need the title to change from the database table(column "entry_name") as each blog post is clicked on. thank you

Comment: When giving error messages, it helps to provide the full error messages. In this case telling us you are getting undefined variable errors is not helpful. If you tell is which variables, in which file, on which line (as given in the error messages) would be more helpful.

Comment: `$entry_name` is undefined in your funciton but you're still trying to pass it to `get_posts()`. That would throw an undefined varaible warning. You should also check that `$result` contains what you expect instead of just assuming that `$result['entry_name']` exists. or you might get undefined index warnings as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you decided to use `return $post->result_array();` in your model you have to fetch the result first in your controller using foreach().
Like so:::

```
foreach($result as $row){
$data['title'] = $row['entry_name'];
}
```

**OR ANOTHER SOLUTION:**

Change your model : `$post->result_array();` to `$post->row_array()`

It should work without using foreach inside your controller. because it only fetch 1 row of your query result array to `$data['title'] = $result['entry_name'];`.

Another solution:

`$post->row();` then in your controller use like so `$data['title'] = $result->entry_name;`

Comment: is this answer ur question?